# Extruder retracts filament while moving from default start line to actual object location

Tags: ultimaker-cura, g-code, extrusion

I am new to 3D printing and recently got a second hand RF1000 and am busy calibrating it. For this I want to print a basic [calibration cube](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1278865). I noticed the print doesn't always start with enough filament in the nozzle. To make sure the starting point for all prints are the same I added this G-Code in the CuraEngine settings:

```
G92 E0 ; start line
G1 F300 E-0.5
G1 X230 Y22 Z0.35 F5000
G1 F800 E13
G1 X20 E25 F1000
```

This works however after this the slicer automatically adds G-Code to move the extruder to the skirt location. This should be fine however I noticed that during the last part of this movement it retracts filament. This causes the start of the actual print to fail. What causes this and how can I change my settings to prevent this?

Thanks for any help or advice you can give!

Below is the G-Code from start until the end of the skirt.

```
;Generated with Cura_SteamEngine 15.01
; Default start code
G28 ; Home extruder
G1 Z15 F100
M107 ; Turn off fan
G90 ; Absolute positioning
M82 ; Extruder in absolute mode
M190 S60
; Activate all used extruder
M104 T0 S210
G92 E0 ; Reset extruder position
; Wait for all used extruders to reach temperature
M109 T0 S210
G92 E0 ; start line
G1 F300 E-0.5
G1 X230 Y22 Z0.35 F5000
G1 F800 E13
G1 X20 E25 F1000
;Layer count: 199
;LAYER:0
M106 S127
G0 F9000 X80.200 Y80.200 Z0.200
;TYPE:SKIRT
G1 F1800 X119.800 Y80.200 E0.44818
G1 X119.800 Y119.800 E0.89636
G1 X80.200 Y119.800 E1.34454
G1 X80.200 Y80.200 E1.79272
G0 F9000 X80.600 Y80.600
G1 F1800 X119.400 Y80.600 E2.23185
G1 X119.400 Y119.400 E2.67097
G1 X80.600 Y119.400 E3.11010
G1 X80.600 Y80.600 E3.54923
G0 F9000 X81.000 Y81.000
G1 F1800 X119.000 Y81.000 E3.97930
G1 X119.000 Y119.000 E4.40937
G1 X81.000 Y119.000 E4.83944
G1 X81.000 Y81.000 E5.26951
G0 F9000 X81.400 Y81.400
G1 F1800 X118.600 Y81.400 E5.69053
G1 X118.600 Y118.600 E6.11155
G1 X81.400 Y118.600 E6.53257
G1 X81.400 Y81.400 E6.95359
G0 F9000 X81.800 Y81.800
G1 F1800 X118.200 Y81.800 E7.36555
G1 X118.200 Y118.200 E7.77751
G1 X81.800 Y118.200 E8.18948
G1 X81.800 Y81.800 E8.60144
G0 F9000 X82.200 Y82.200
G1 F1800 X117.800 Y82.200 E9.00435
G1 X117.800 Y117.800 E9.40726
G1 X82.200 Y117.800 E9.81017
G1 X82.200 Y82.200 E10.21308
G0 F9000 X82.600 Y82.600
G1 F1800 X117.400 Y82.600 E10.60693
G1 X117.400 Y117.400 E11.00079
G1 X82.600 Y117.400 E11.39465
G1 X82.600 Y82.600 E11.78850
G0 F9000 X83.000 Y83.000
G1 F1800 X117.000 Y83.000 E12.17330
G1 X117.000 Y117.000 E12.55810
G1 X83.000 Y117.000 E12.94290
G1 X83.000 Y83.000 E13.32771
G0 F9000 X83.400 Y83.400
G1 F1800 X116.600 Y83.400 E13.70345
G1 X116.600 Y116.600 E14.07920
G1 X83.400 Y116.600 E14.45495
G1 X83.400 Y83.400 E14.83069
G0 F9000 X83.800 Y83.800
G1 F1800 X116.200 Y83.800 E15.19739
G1 X116.200 Y116.200 E15.56408
G1 X83.800 Y116.200 E15.93077
G1 X83.800 Y83.800 E16.29747
G0 F9000 X84.200 Y84.200
G1 F1800 X115.800 Y84.200 E16.65511
G1 X115.800 Y115.800 E17.01274
G1 X84.200 Y115.800 E17.37038
G1 X84.200 Y84.200 E17.72802
G0 F9000 X84.600 Y84.600
G1 F1800 X115.400 Y84.600 E18.07661
G1 X115.400 Y115.400 E18.42519
G1 X84.600 Y115.400 E18.77378
G1 X84.600 Y84.600 E19.12236
G0 F9000 X85.000 Y85.000
G1 F1800 X115.000 Y85.000 E19.46189
G1 X115.000 Y115.000 E19.80142
G1 X85.000 Y115.000 E20.14095
G1 X85.000 Y85.000 E20.48048
G0 F9000 X85.400 Y85.400
G1 F1800 X114.600 Y85.400 E20.81096
G1 X114.600 Y114.600 E21.14144
G1 X85.400 Y114.600 E21.47191
G1 X85.400 Y85.400 E21.80239
G0 F9000 X85.800 Y85.800
G1 F1800 X114.200 Y85.800 E22.12381
G1 X114.200 Y114.200 E22.44523
G1 X85.800 Y114.200 E22.76665
G1 X85.800 Y85.800 E23.08808
G0 F9000 X86.200 Y86.200
G1 F1800 X113.800 Y86.200 E23.40045
G1 X113.800 Y113.800 E23.71281
G1 X86.200 Y113.800 E24.02518
G1 X86.200 Y86.200 E24.33755
G0 F9000 X86.600 Y86.600
G1 F1800 X113.400 Y86.600 E24.64086
G1 X113.400 Y113.400 E24.94418
G1 X86.600 Y113.400 E25.24749
G1 X86.600 Y86.600 E25.55081
G0 F9000 X87.000 Y87.000
G1 F1800 X113.000 Y87.000 E25.84507
G1 X113.000 Y113.000 E26.13932
G1 X87.000 Y113.000 E26.43358
G1 X87.000 Y87.000 E26.72784
G0 F9000 X87.400 Y87.400
G1 F1800 X112.600 Y87.400 E27.01305
G1 X112.600 Y112.600 E27.29826
G1 X87.400 Y112.600 E27.58346
G1 X87.400 Y87.400 E27.86867
G0 F9000 X87.800 Y87.800
G1 F1800 X112.200 Y87.800 E28.14482
G1 X112.200 Y112.200 E28.42097
G1 X87.800 Y112.200 E28.69712
G1 X87.800 Y87.800 E28.97327
G0 F9000 X88.200 Y88.200
G1 F1800 X111.800 Y88.200 E29.24037
G1 X111.800 Y111.800 E29.50747
G1 X88.200 Y111.800 E29.77457
G1 X88.200 Y88.200 E30.04166
G0 F9000 X88.600 Y88.600
G1 F1800 X111.400 Y88.600 E30.29971
G1 X111.400 Y111.400 E30.55775
G1 X88.600 Y111.400 E30.81579
G1 X88.600 Y88.600 E31.07384
G0 F9000 X89.000 Y89.000
G1 F1800 X111.000 Y89.000 E31.32282
G1 X111.000 Y111.000 E31.57181
G1 X89.000 Y111.000 E31.82080
G1 X89.000 Y89.000 E32.06979
G0 F9000 X89.400 Y89.400
G1 F1800 X110.600 Y89.400 E32.30973
G1 X110.600 Y110.600 E32.54966
G1 X89.400 Y110.600 E32.78960
G1 X89.400 Y89.400 E33.02953
G0 F9000 X89.800 Y89.800
G1 F1800 X110.200 Y89.800 E33.26041
G1 X110.200 Y110.200 E33.49129
G1 X89.800 Y110.200 E33.72217
G1 X89.800 Y89.800 E33.95305
G0 F9000 X90.600 Y90.600
```

Comment: Hi Stefan, welcome to 3D Printing.SE! Please define `This causes the start of the actual print to fail`. Priming blobs are very useful indeed, they are commonly used. After the blob the filament should retract, the head moves and then extrudes to fill the cavity in the nozzle again.

Comment: Hi Oscar, thanks for your response. The problem is that the filament retracts while moving from priming to actual print. This causes there to be no filament loaded in the extruder when the actual print starts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The problem is that you prime the nozzle, but don't reset the filament length.**

With your last priming action:

`G1 X20 E25 F1000`

You deposit a line that is followed by a move to the start of the skirt:

`G0 F9000 X80.200 Y80.200 Z0.200`

The printing of the start of the skirt is done by:

`G1 F1800 X119.800 Y80.200 E0.44818`

Notice the `E` term in your final priming line and the skirt print command; it goes from **`E25`** to **`E0.44818`**, as these specify absolute movement, this results in a retraction of about 24.5 mm. What you should do is implement a `G92 E0` after your last priming command to fix this incorrect retraction behavior.

---

<sub>*Please also do note that you are using a very old version of the CuraEngine, maybe it is possible to update to a newer version as well; depending on the slicer you use.*</sub>